# Java ASM Manipulate IntInsnNodes

Tags: java, java-bytecode-asm

I'm kind of new to ASM.

I'm trying to disallow int searching in decompilers, so I'm trying to negate a mathematical operation multiple times.

Example: `int i = 10;` --> `int i = 2 + 8;`

I've already done that, but I want to do it like this:

```
int i = -(-(2+8));
```

If you know, how I could do this, please tell me!
Thanks!

Comment: You really think, this will confuse any decompiler? Besides, if you already managed to rewrite the constant as sum, then, what's the problem with negation?

Comment: The problem is, it does only negate the first number, not the whole sum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to replace a single `BIPUSH 10` (`IntInsnNode`) instruction with a chain of

```
ICONST_2 // InsnNode
BIPUSH 8 // IntInsnNode
IADD     // InsnNode
INEG     // InsnNode
INEG     // InsnNode
```

If your goal is that the `BIPUSH 10` should not be discoverable when opening a class in a hex editor, this might do the trick but I would hardly call this obfuscation. It is easy enough to reduce this chain of bytecodes to the original value.

Finally, note that this replacement changes the stack size requirement such that you probably need to adjust the `maxStack` variable.